# Docusign and Dynamics 365 integration

Tags: docusignapi, dynamics-365

We have installed docusign solution in Dynamics 365 and can create documents that are signed correct.
The issue we currently have is that we don't get status updates to Docusign transactions in Dynamics 365 unless we manually click "update statuses" in Docusign.
It says it should do this automatically in the documentation but it doesn't seem to work. This is btw. only a trial at the moment untill we are sure we can use it with responses back to Dynamics 365.
Does anyone know what could be missing. If we can publish the status messages by clicking "update statuses" the "link" between Dynamics 365 and Docusign should be ok. 
Hope someone can point us in the right direction here, thanks :)

Comment: This question is not about programming. Maybe it would be better in a different forum.

Comment: I'd suggest that you contact DocuSign Support about this issue with their Dynamics 365 integration (support@microsoft.com). You're unlikely to get help here on Stack Overflow, because Stack Overflow is a venue specifically for programming questions.

Comment: I agree with Kim. Please contact DocuSign support

Comment: DocuSign support said we should ask in here, well back to them then :)

Comment: @JackDallSølbeck I HIGHLY DOUBT Docusign referred you to SO lol

Answer (score 1):

I found that the DocuSign built solution for Dynamics integration just wasn't good enough, and ultimately we built a custom integration to the DocuSign API running in Workflow, and then launched an azure hosted web service to listen for the call backs and automatically update our CRM records. Also wasn't impressed with Docusign pricing, and honest would recommend finding an alternative provider.